# phonegap 2.6 and android API 2.2

Tags: android, cordova

I'm started with a new phonegap application and I want to use the 2.2 Android API.
I've got error even in the initial project.

I can resolve these problems using a major version of the API (4.x).

Is there a way to build application with PhoneGap 2.6 for android API 2.2?
maybe I do somenthing wrong in the

```
 ./create <p1> <p2> <p3>
```

project.

using oracle-jdk7U21 and android-sdk-linux
the ANDROID_BIN is set to

```
 android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

**EDIT and SOLVED**

It's everything fine for compatibility build with Android API 16 and using a device that support API 8.

so i figured out it's ok using the android sdk 4.x and run on device with andorid 2.2 (until now)

Answer (score 0):

for downloading android sdk follow the link [Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html)
and for [phonegap eclipse](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html)

Comment: i figured out that i can build with api '4.x' and the projet it's still compatible with android api 2.2
so it's everything fine.